# Play Framework 2.4 Scala in production error "could not create play_evolutions table"

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to deploy my Play Framework application.
I have database backup from test server with some data. I rolled up database backup from test server to production server database. And tried to run Play Framework. It ran without problem before in this situation. But now on this server it gives me error:

> play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi - could not create
>   play_evolutions table org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:
>   relation "play_evolutions" already exists

What does it mean? Yes, there is play_evolutions table but why it tries to create it again? How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can drop the play_evolutions table (If it's OK) and run the Playframework once again.

Answer (score 0):

it might be because of the conf/evolutins.default/*.sql
or you can disable evolution by configuring the application.conf file

## You can disable evolutions if needed

## evolutionplugin=disabled